# Get output image resolution before capturing images with AVCaptureSession

Tags: objective-c, iphone, output, resolution, avcapturesession

I'm developing an iPhone application in which I have to use AVCaptureSession to capture an image from the rear Camera. Each time the application starts, it will receive 2 values from a server, the first value is the AVCaptureSession's *sessionPreset* property, and the second is a GCRect for clipping the output image (the coordinate of this rectangle is corresponding to the output image's resolution).

Now the problem is, I have to "draw" that clipping rectangle onto the camera preview, which means I'll have to map the coordinate of the clipping rectangle to another "proper" coordinate of the camera preview (since the sessionPreset varies each time the application starts). I've search on Apple's documentation but I couldn't find a way to get the resolution of the output image. I need that output resolution in order to do the clipping rectangle's mapping.

This is the code where I start my AVCaptureSession in my view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Capture Session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc]init];
    session.sessionPreset = _sessionPreset; //this _sessionPreset varies each time my app starts

    //Add device
    AVCaptureDevice *device =
    [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //Input
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:nil];

    if (!input)
    {
       NSLog(@"No Input");
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    //Output
    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *output = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG,AVVideoCodecKey,nil];
    [output setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:output];


    //Preview Layer
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
    UIView *myView = self.view;
    previewLayer.frame = myView.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];

    //Start capture session
    [session startRunning];
    //Now I want to draw the rectangle after the session starts
}
```

Thanks in advance fellas :)

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, I found the answer for my question here:

[iOS8 video dimension, CMVideoDimensions returns 0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25902122/ios8-video-dimension-cmvideodimensions-returns-0-0)

Just make sure to catch the notification after [captureSession startRunning];